# Loading pscx module fails with Error in TypeData

Tags: powershell, pscx

I'm getting the following error when I try to load the pscx PowerShell Module.

```
Import-Module : The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: Error in TypeData "System.TimeSpan": Type "Pscx.TypeConverters.WmiDateTimeTypeConverter" should be either TypeConverter or PSTypeConverter. Error in TypeData "System.DateTime": Type "Pscx.TypeConverters.WmiDateTimeTypeConverter" should be either TypeConverter or PSTypeConverter. At C:\Users\<username>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1:1 char:1
+ Import-Module pscx
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Import-Module], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatXmlUpdateException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

Any ideas why I would be getting this error.  It seemed to start happening after I updated my Windows to the latest Windows 10 update a few weeks back.

Below are the PowerShell version details:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.17134.228
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.17134.228
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

I have inspected the dll with DotPeek and the Pscx.TypeConverters.WmiDateTimeTypeConverter type does inherit from PSTypeConverter.

Comment: Have you checked the types meta file in the module?  Based on the error message, that appears to be where it stems.

Comment: I see this in the Pscx.Wmi.Type.ps1xml file:  `<Type>
    <Name>System.TimeSpan</Name>
    <TypeConverter>
      <TypeName>Pscx.TypeConverters.WmiDateTimeTypeConverter</TypeName>
    </TypeConverter>
  </Type>`